# How to create dynamic document name in docusign template?

Tags: docusignapi

Have a docusign template and want the name of pdf document which is sent after completion to be dynamic.

currently its named as "Document"

want this to be named as "Document fullName" where fullName is a custom textTab

Comment: Tried this merge field [[RecipientName]] . Its coming on subject but not on docusign name

Answer (score 0):

You could make an [updateDocument](https://developers.docusign.com/docs/esign-rest-api/reference/envelopes/envelopedocuments/update/) call after sending the envelope to change the document name to include the recipients `fullName`. You cannot make this call after the envelope is Completed and has been signed. Therefore you'll need to do it before or immediately after you create the envelope. Best practice would be to set the desired document name before the envelope is sent.